# how to pass custom Throwable with some additional data in java

Tags: java

This accept only Throwable type->

```
Instrumentation.reportError(exception)
```

i have created custom Exception class :

```
public class AppdIdentityTrackException extends Throwable {


    public AppdIdentityTrackException(){
        super();

    }
   public AppdIdentityTrackException(int responseCode,String URl,String errorMessage){
        this.responseCode=responseCode;
        this.URl=URl;
        this.errorMessage=errorMessage;
   }
```

and passing in method like this ;

```
private void sendAppDTrackData(Response response, String pageName, String errorMessage)  {
        try {

            throw new AppdIdentityTrackException(1,"","");
        } catch (AppdIdentityTrackException exception) {
            Instrumentation.reportError(exception);
        }
    }
```

but exception not behave like throwable type of object can any one please suggest me how to pass make throwable and pass throwable type of object.

Comment: Don't extend `Throwable` directly: extend `Exception` or `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Why throw it only to catch it immediately? Just use `reportError(new AppdIdentityTrackException(1,"",""))`.

Comment: Is `Instrumentation` something you wrote? Why do you throw `AppdIdentityTrackException` to catch it immediately? Why not just pass it to the `reportError` method?

Comment: *exception not behave like throwable type of object* - say what again?

Comment: Instrumentation is AppDynamic class https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO45/Customize+the+Android+Instrumentation trying to implement this Report Errors and Exceptions search it

Comment: @AndyTurner i changed with same let me check will let you know

Comment: @AndyTurner not working

Comment: It's generally a bad practice to extend `Throwable`. You should extend `Exception` (or one of its subclasses) instead. You'll still be able to pass it to `reportError` because an `Exception` _is_ a `Throwable` (i.e. class Exception extends Throwable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the message string you can override throwable's getMessage() method.

```
@Override
public String getMessage() {
  return responseCode + " " + URl + " " + errorMessage;
}
```

If it's something else we will need more info on what Instrumentation.reportError(string) is doing.

Comment: thanx  wait let me try this

Comment: but i want pass it Inseturmention.reportError(which accept throwable)

Comment: yeah just add that to your AppdIdentityTrackException class.